# I can't get Laravel Echo Server and Redis to work in production

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, apache2, laravel-echo

After going around a good number of forums and GIT questions, I've come to the end of a solution, I don't understand why my websockets server isn't working.

I'm using Lavavel 10 on an Ubuntu server, with Apache2 and letsencrypt.

First, here are the configurations and pieces of code used:

.env

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "https://example.net",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": false,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem",
    "sslKeyPath": "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "*",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

app.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
let e = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
})
e.channel('laravel_database_signals')
 .listen('SignalCreatedEvent', (e) => {
    document.getElementById('latest_signal').innerText = JSON.stringify(e.signal);
})
```

So, I started Redis on the server using systemd.
When I start laravel-echo-server, it's showing me this :

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.3

Starting server...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!
```

example.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin contact@example.net
    ServerName example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.net/public

    <Directory /var/www/example.net/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

example-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443 *:6001>

    ServerAdmin contact@example.net
    ServerName example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.net/public

    <Directory /var/www/example.net/public>
       Options +FollowSymlinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.net/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:6001/$1 [P,L]

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLProxyEngine on

<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But when I load my page that's calling app.js, there's no log that tell user is listening.

It's like Redis and Laravel Echo Server can't communicate together.

Redis is giving me good logs on monitor when I try to push an event.

Does somebody see something that's wrong in my configuration ?

Thanks.